# Border with 2 fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can I apply this design specially brown border , how can i apply something like that with 2 fragments and list of static buttons at the end of screen .

sorry i cannot upload image website error :"You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

so you can find image at this link

[image](http://dc589.2shared.com/download/h_cQZ1jC/unnamed2.jpg?tsid=20130615-172558-25080a02)

this is my attempts

fragment_list.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"    
         >
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chapter_list_entry"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="28dip"
            />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/chapterid_list_entry"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textSize="28dip"
               android:visibility="invisible"  />

    </LinearLayout>
```

hadith_details_activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/country_details_fragment_container"    
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

hadith_details_fragment_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/country_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/hadith_list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="rewaya.books.alhadith.HadithExpandableListFragment"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it can help us if you will upload an image of what you want exactly :)

Comment: you will find it at this link http://dc589.2shared.com/download/h_cQZ1jC/unnamed2.jpg?tsid=20130615-172558-25080a02

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.DetailsFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.ListFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OK, till now i implement this using 4 layout XML file

Comment: You can add any number of ragments and buttons as you want. Just add them the same way.

Comment: I modified question with my attempts , i was implement design with 4 XML layout file , so please check this , and help me how to modify my code to implement this design , and please don't forget border screen and border between two fragment .thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following:

- First draw a big `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` that will be the container for the other components
- add a `LinearLayout` that will contain two other `FrameLayouts` that will be inflated with your fragments - if you use `LinearLayout` you can use the weight feature to split the fragments width proportionaly
- below the LinearLayout you can add a new container layout (`Relative` or `Linear` `Layout`) where you add those buttons

To set borders to your fragment, you can set a background image/drawable having those borders to your `FrameLayouts`..

I hope it helps.